# What is the reasonable size for a single responsive web page

Tags: jquery, html, symfony, web

I am developing a Website which is designed to have lots of large images as `background`.

I am also using `media-query` because it should be responsive and have a different background for each screen sizes. The total size of the images themselves is **10MB** excluded the small images which may file up to **300KB** only.

The `scripts` (bootstrap, jQuery and custom js), `styles` (bootstrap and my custom css) and `HTML` are just less than **1MB**.

In conclusion I am loading a more or less **11MB** web page this is just the Index page. The assets are already compressed and is placed in a CDN on my server.

My problem here is when someone visited the website for the first time it takes too much time to load the page, specially when the visitor's internet connection is slower than standard speed. It almost takes more than **20sec** to load the entire page in worse cases more than a minute and obviously there is something wrong.

Is there a reasonable or standard size for a single web page to follow? I am also using `symfony2` maybe there's a plugin or alike that can help me.

Here by the way is the website. [LINK](https://pickld.me/) Thanks.

Comment: 20 sec is too long you may lose your users. But website looks good.  I have a small lag scrolling your pages. Probably, it's better to consider reducing image sizes. Took me 10 sec to load btw, always depends on your speed

Comment: Awesome site buddy!! :)

Comment: @SaidKholov Thanks for the feed back. Yes I think that the internet speed is always a big factor. I am recoding this page hoping to get things faster. Thank you.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Thanks buddy. :) Im glad you liked it. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao dig in further, you might also like the app. :D

Comment: Already digged in and definitely, Am going for it.. :)

Answer (score 1):

11MB is WAY too big for any single web page. However, you can get much better performance out of Symfony with just a few tweaks.

One thing you can do right now is use Assetic to manage your asset files, and minify them before they are sent to the client.

Also, make sure APC is running on your server. You can check `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` output and do a page search for "APC", or run `php -i | grep apc` on the command line.

There are also online image optimizers, just google "image optimizer" and you'll find tons for each image type. (I can't post a link, because this site isn't letting me post more than two).

**Reference**

- [Symfony Performance Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/performance.html)
- [Symfony Performance Blog Post](http://labs.octivi.com/mastering-symfony2-performance-internals/)

Comment: Before I upload the assets they are already minified and the assets are not much of a problem, the images are. 

What does this APC do? 

And also the images are already optimized I used **PNGYU**

Im hoping to find some trick to make it faster because I cant either reduce the images quality as it is right now (compressed) and the design of the page.

Comment: APC is a PHP OpCode cache. It makes PHP run faster. Also, you could [HTTP Cache](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html) to bypass the php framework all together as your site doesn't seem to have too many dynamic elements.

Comment: I checked it and it is running.

Comment: You could get a little smaller assets by loading them from a [separate CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) from your own... They (most likely) will already be cached on your user's browser.